# Definite and Indefinite integral give different results for piecewise function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I have the following function:

$$
f(q,y)=
\begin{cases}
 \tfrac{11720+p}{37791360} & -11720<p<-7720 \\
 0 & \text{True}
\end{cases}
$$

where $p = 443\ y-777600\ \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{q \lambda }{4 \pi }\right)$.

*Mathematica* Code:

```
f[q_,y_]=Piecewise[
          {{(11720+443 y-777600 ArcSin[(q λ)/(4 π)])/37791360,
            -11720<443 y-777600 ArcSin[(q λ)/(4 π)]<-7720}},
            0]
```

Now, if I take an indefinite integral over `y`,

```
weird[q_, y_] = Integrate[f[q, y], y]
```

which gives

$$
g(q,y)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{293 y}{944784}+\frac{443 y^2}{75582720}-\frac{5}{243} y\ \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\text{qy} \lambda }{4 \pi }\right) & -11720<p<-7720 \\
 0 & \text{True}
\end{cases}
$$

I can then evaluate this function at my endpoints `{-1,1}` to get the definite integral.

However, I could also have *Mathematica* run the definite integral directly.

```
weirder[q_, y_] = Integrate[f[q, y], {y, -1, 1}]
```

which gives

[image: something really big]

Plain Text Version:

```
\[Piecewise]    (293-19440 ArcSin[(q \[Lambda])/(4 \[Pi])])/472392             907/86400<ArcSin[(q \[Lambda])/(4 \[Pi])]<=1253/86400
(1/33483144960)(-111170729+29544134400 ArcSin[(q \[Lambda])/(4 \[Pi])]-1209323520000     ArcSin[(q \[Lambda])/(4 \[Pi])]^2-12006144000 I Log[4     \[Pi]]-604661760000 Log[4 \[Pi]]^2+12006144000 I Log[I q \[Lambda]+Sqrt[16 \[Pi]^2-q^2 \[Lambda]^2]]+1209323520000 Log[4 \[Pi]] Log[I q \[Lambda]+Sqrt[16 \[Pi]^2-q^2 \[Lambda]^2]]-604661760000 Log[I q \[Lambda]+Sqrt[16 \[Pi]^2-q^2 \[Lambda]^2]]^2)  7277/777600<ArcSin[(q \[Lambda])/(4 \[Pi])]<=907/86400
(1/33483144960)(147938569-37142841600 ArcSin[(q \[Lambda])/(4 \[Pi])]+1209323520000 ArcSin[(q \[Lambda])/(4 \[Pi])]^2+18226944000 I Log[4 \[Pi]]+604661760000 Log[4 \[Pi]]^2-18226944000 I Log[I q \[Lambda]+Sqrt[16 \[Pi]^2-q^2 \[Lambda]^2]]-1209323520000 Log[4 \[Pi]] Log[I q \[Lambda]+Sqrt[16 \[Pi]^2-q^2 \[Lambda]^2]]+604661760000 Log[I q \[Lambda]+Sqrt[16 \[Pi]^2-q^2 \[Lambda]^2]]^2)   1253/86400<ArcSin[(q \[Lambda])/(4 \[Pi])]<12163/777600
0   True
```

This result, depending on my value of `q`, is different that the result given by the indefinite integral.  Specifically of note are the log terms, which did not appear in the indefinite integral.

Why is the definite integral different from subtracting the end points of the indefinite integral?  Which of these results should I trust?

Comment: Can you give a value of $q$ and $\lambda$ that actually give a different numerical result?

Comment: When the indefinite integral has discontunities, substituting the endpoints in the indefinite integral expression gives incorrect results. You get the correct result for the definite integral. Check the section `Possible Issues` subsection `Definite Integral` under `Integrate` in documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the indefinite integral has discontunities (as is the case for your integrand for some values of `q` and `alpha`), substituting the endpoints in the indefinite integral expression gives incorrect results. To get the correct result you need to use the definite integral.

Please see the section `Possible Issues` subsection [`Definite Integral`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Integrate.html#21924) under `Integrate` in docs. The issue is also discussed at length in this Wolfram Blog entry: [Mathematica and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/).

Comment: A particularly nasty example is $$\int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{−x}}{\sin x}dx$$ which is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5575946/198315). Of particular relevance is this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5584403/198315) which discusses how the changing the limits effected the outcome.

Comment: I used this question as a duplicate target, so I added a references to your answer pointing to a wolfram blog entry on the same issue. Please feel free to revert the change if you find it inappropriate,

Comment: Thank you @MarcoB.