# Indefinite vs. definite integration contradiction in Version 11.3

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

When evaluating the same integral using indefinite integration **(method 1**) or definite integration (**method 2**) I get different answers:  `method 1 = 0` and `method 2 = 10*Pi*I`.  **Method 2** is the correct answer, however I need the result in the form of a function so I need correct answer for method 1.  **Any ideas on what the problem is?**

**METHOD 1:**

```
Clear[r];

Clear[z0];

contour = z0 + r Exp[I theta];

f = (z - 3)^2*(z^3 + 1);

integrand = ((D[f, z] / f ) /. z -> contour)*D[contour, theta];

indefintegral = Integrate[integrand, theta];

defintegral = (indefintegral /. {r->5, z0 -> 0, theta -> 2*Pi})- 
(indefintegral /. {r -> 5, z0-> 0, theta -> 0})
```

**METHOD 2:**

```
r = 5;

z0 = 3;

contour = z0 + r*Exp[I theta];

f = (z - 3)^2*(z^3 + 1);

integrand = ((D[f, z] / f ) /. z -> contour)*D[contour, theta];

defintegral = Integrate[integrand, {theta, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Comment: Your indefinite integral expression may have discontinuities, in which case substituting the limits in the indefinite integral expression gives incorrect results, which are avoided by the definite integral calculation. This is discussed in the "Possible Issues" subsection of the [`Integrate` docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html). See also: [Definite and Indefinite integral give different results for piecewise function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2240/27951).

Comment: If you do the subsittution for `r` and `z0` into `indefintegral`, then plot the real and imaginary parts over `theta`, you will see the latter has discontinuities. Basically this is what `@MarcoB surmised.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definite and Indefinite integral give different results for piecewise function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2240/definite-and-indefinite-integral-give-different-results-for-piecewise-function)

Comment: OK, perhaps, but I plotted the real and imaginary parts of the integrand (from method 1) using values r=5 and z0 = 0.  As expected, it is easily visually seen the real part will integrate to 0 while imaginary part integrates to a positive number.  No obvious discontinuity in real part.  Further, this is a simple application of the argument principle in complex analysis.  The integrand itself contains only a polynomial in the denominator, so it has 5 poles that are interior to the contour (a circle of radius 5).  The integrand must be holomorphic on the contour of integration.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Ok I'am not very strong in contour integration,but we can easily visually seen: `Plot[indefintegral /. {r -> 5, z0 -> 0} // 
  Im, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]` obvious discontinuity in  imaginary parts.

Comment: Don't plot indefintegral, plot integrand.  It is clearly a smooth function.  Plot[integrand/. {r->5, z0->0}//Im, {theta,0, 2 Pi}]

Comment: `1/z` is smooth along the segment connecting `1-I` to `1+I`. The antiderivative produced by Mathematica, `Log[z]`, still crosses a branch cut. As for the CIF, the number of poles inside depends on those values for `r` and `z0`, which are not when `indefintegral` is computed. So Newton-Leibniz will not apply if there are branch cut crossings, which there are.